# MySQL query requires help in forming

Tags: mysql, sql

Generate a list of users who have RECEIVED > 5 Kudos on average for each activity

Previously we have tried using:

```
SELECT userid
from user_activity.ActivityID =activity.ActivityID
where activity. ActivityID in
(select activity inner join Kudo
on activity.ActivityID = Kudo.ActivityID
group by activity.ActivityID
having count(*) > 5);
```

However it only gives the output of users who receives >5 kudos for at least one activity, we require the list of users who receives >5 kudos per activity on average

[image: ERD diagram for forming of SQL queries]

Comment: I can't follow the design of your database tables.  Please edit your question and make it easier to understand.

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data and expected output as text (you could reduce the threshold from 5 to 2 )

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This is impossible to answer with the published information - how do you distinguish received and given kudos?

Comment: @P.Salmon has asked the correct question, We cannot answer your question until you tell us how you distinguish received and given kudos

Comment: To obtain result for the received kudo, we need to link the kudo.activityID to Activity.ActivityID, then to user-activity, then to user. I think that by using the count function, we will be able to count the number of kudos given to each activity of a user

Comment: What is your query to obtain the received kudo .. should've start with that

Comment: The problem i am facing is I am unable to come up with the queries

Comment: If like that, you should think about how do you identify a received kudo first. Then you start building your query from there. Or maybe you can add another column in your kudo table to differentiate between received and given kudos.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT   userid,username
FROM     user
WHERE    userid IN ( SELECT   userid 
                     FROM     kudo 
                     GROUP BY userid,activityid  --- adding activityid in group by
                     HAVING   COUNT(*) > 5 );
```

Comment: I can't help feeling activityid has to come into it somewhere.

Comment: Oh yes! I read his question again and I _"5 Kudos on average for **each activity**"_ ..

Comment: This gives me the list of users who gives kudo, however what i require is the list of users who receives kudos

Comment: May I know what is the data store in the Kudo table? I see there are two columns and assuming `ActivityId` holds the receive or give value?

Comment: ActivityID holds the receive value

Comment: If the user receives a Kudo, the ActivityID value would be..? And if the user gives a Kudo, the ActivityID value would be..?

Comment: It will be the acitivty ID of the activity that the kudo is given to